# Xcode Storyboard Assistant NOT automatically dragging and dropping

Tags: xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFSX7.jpg)

The Issue I am having is XCODE will not allow me to automatically connect things with IB when I drag and drop items from the display of the storyboard.

ANSWER

IF YOUR HAVING THIS ISSUE AND USING A MACBOOK THAN MOVE THE COMPONENT AT THE SAME TIME YOU HOLD THE CONTROL BUTTON IT WILL WORK.

IF YOU READ OTHER FIXES SAYING CHANGE THE CLASS TO VIEW CONTROLLER UNKLESS YOU CLICK THE SMALL BLACK BOX ABOVE THE VIEW OF YOUR STORYBOARD / UI YOU WILL NOT FIND THE OPTION VIEW CONTROLLER IN THE LIST OF OPTIONS THIS MAY CONFUSE YOU